# How to assemble and align svg?

Tags: html, xml, svg, path

As you can see the image has three parts: the marker, the circle and the icon:

```html
<svg width="58" height="66.667" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:#eee">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M37.434 56.755C49.337 53.142 58 42.082 58 29 58 12.984 45.016 0 29 0S0 12.984 0 29c0 13.083 8.663 24.142 20.566 27.755l6.834 9.112a2 2 0 0 0 3.2 0z" fill="#fff"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M29 55c14.36 0 26-11.64 26-26S43.36 3 29 3 3 14.64 3 29s11.64 26 26 26z" fill="#000000"/>
<path d="M11 9H9V2H7v7H5V2H3v7c0 2.12 1.66 3.84 3.75 3.97V22h2.5v-9.03C11.34 12.84 13 11.12 13 9V2h-2v7zm5-3v8h2.5v8H21V2c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 4z" fill="#ffffff"/>
</svg>
```

The icon is not centered.

Anyone know how to reorder all of this?

Comment: By learning what the **M** does in an SVG d-path: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path

Comment: Please add `transform="translate(17,16)"` to the last path

Comment: or change that last path to start with **M28 25** (11+17 , 9+16)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman this would do in the case of an all-relative path, i.e all lowercase commands. In the case of the path above M28 25 would distort the path instead of moving it

Comment: use https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/\

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question well,you want to align the images inside the image or align it to the center of your html?

If you want to align to the center of your html webpage, you can use this
`transform: translate((x-axis)px,((y-axis)px);` on your CSS,for example `transform: translate(300px,50px);`

If you want to align the items inside another image, you need to set your main-svg as `position:relative` and place your other svg `position:absolute` and you can adjust the position much easier.

Well,Hope it helps, you might have better solution from others, I've just picked up html and CSS weeks ago.